# Dynamic library "forwarding"

Tags: c, linker, shared-libraries

[Edit: In short, the question is: when I link against a dynamic library that is linked against another dynamic library, do I have to *explicitly* link against that as well?]

I saw something like this in a piece of software. It doesn't work and now I am wondering whether it is supposed to work. Can I link a library "bar" dynamically against another library "foo" and then link against that library to access the symbols from "foo" (because "bar" should want to be linked to "foo")? (I am using linux and gcc 4.8.2 in case that matters.)

Concretely suppose I have the three files below. Now I do

```
gcc -c -Wall -Werror -fpic foo.c
gcc -shared -olibfoo.so foo.o
```

at which point I would usually do

```
gcc -o program main.c -L. -lfoo
```

to get a working program. Now instead I do

```
gcc -shared -olibbar.so -L. -lfoo
gcc -o program main.c -L. -lbar
```

This doesn't work:

```
/tmp/cciNSTyI.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `foo'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Should it?

foo.h

```
#ifndef foo_h__
#define foo_h__

extern void foo(void);

#endif
```

foo.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(void)
{
  puts("foo");
}
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "foo.h"

int main(void)
{
  puts("Library test...");
  foo();
  return 0;
}
```

Edit: I wrote an answer about my understanding of what's going on below.

One thing I'm still not quite clear about is the order of arguments: If (with a file bar.c as in that answer) I link bar with the lines (note the position of "bar.o")

```
gcc -o program main.c -L. -lbar
gcc -shared -olibbar.so -L. -lfoo bar.o
```

then it "bar" does not depend on "foo":

```
> readelf -d libbar.so
Dynamic section at offset 0xe18 contains 24 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x000000000000000c (INIT)               0x5a8
 [...]
```

Comment: May be you need to clarify _Now instead I do_ part. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to "forward" dynamically linked libraries.

When you link against any library, statically or dynamically, you actually enable your main executable to call on the functions/symbols defined in the linked library.

In your case, the library `bar`, does not have the function `foo()` defined in it. So when `bar.so` is created, the symbols generated are registered in the symbol table of your main executable - `program`. As, the symbols in the `bar` lib do not contain any function called `foo()`, it doesn't get registered in the symbol table of `program`. So when `foo()` gets called during time, the loader tries to find the .so in which `foo()` would be defined among all the libraries you linked during compiling `program`. Hence the run time error. It doesn't show a compile time error because you had included the `foo.h` header file to it.

You need to explicitly link all the libraries of which symbols(functions, variables, constants, etc.) you want to reference in the code being compiled.

Answer (score 1):

> when I link against a dynamic library that is linked against another dynamic library, do I have to explicitly link against that as well?

No.

That other library must be linked against shared libraries it requires, otherwise it would be one massive fuster cluck (the one you get with `.a` files).

Imagine someone else adding a shared library dependency to a shared library you use. That would cause your application to fail at link-time (at best) or run-time. This is why shared libraries carry their own dependencies.

You can use `readelf` utility to examine shared library dependencies, e.g.:

```
$ readelf -d /usr/lib64/libboost_wave-mt.so

Dynamic section at offset 0x12fd58 contains 30 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libpthread.so.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [librt.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libboost_filesystem-mt.so.5]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libboost_thread-mt.so.5]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libboost_date_time-mt.so.5]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libboost_system-mt.so.5]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libm.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x000000000000000e (SONAME)             Library soname: [libboost_wave-mt.so.5]
 0x000000000000000c (INIT)               0xb49f0
 0x000000000000000d (FINI)               0x10c018
 0x000000006ffffef5 (GNU_HASH)           0x1b8
 0x0000000000000005 (STRTAB)             0xbe08
 0x0000000000000006 (SYMTAB)             0x2cb8
 0x000000000000000a (STRSZ)              637705 (bytes)
 0x000000000000000b (SYMENT)             24 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000003 (PLTGOT)             0x3308a8
 0x0000000000000002 (PLTRELSZ)           7584 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000014 (PLTREL)             RELA
 0x0000000000000017 (JMPREL)             0xb2c50
 0x0000000000000007 (RELA)               0xa8600
 0x0000000000000008 (RELASZ)             42576 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000009 (RELAENT)            24 (bytes)
 0x000000006ffffffe (VERNEED)            0xa8530
 0x000000006fffffff (VERNEEDNUM)         4
 0x000000006ffffff0 (VERSYM)             0xa7912
 0x000000006ffffff9 (RELACOUNT)          405
 0x0000000000000000 (NULL)               0x0
```

Note `NEEDED` attributes - these are the shared libraries that get loaded automatically when you load this shared library.

---

In

```
gcc -shared -olibbar.so -L. -lfoo
```

You produce a shared library from a shared library. In this case you need to do *partial linking* with `--relocatable` linker option:

```
gcc -shared -Wl,--relocatable -olibbar.so -L. -lfoo
```

Comment: Thank you. That explicitly having to link against all dependencies would spoil the idea of libraries is a good point. But then libfoo.so should appear as NEEDED line in libbar.so, right? But it doesn't.

Your second answer I couldn't understand/get to work. What I want is really a shared library libbar that does nothing other than depend on libfoo.

Answer (score 0):

This is following up on the answer by Maxim Egorushkin (in particular using readelf was instructive).

First it seems that only libraries are marked as "NEEDED" if they are actually needed anywhere, i.e. if some symbol defined by them is used at all. In the example in the question this is of course not the case.

Second, even if via these dependencies "foo" ends up being linked in, its symbols are still not available to main.c unless it is linked in explicitly.

To verify this behaviour, consider the files

bar.h

```
#ifndef bar_h__
#define bar_h__

extern void bar(void);

#endif
```

and

bar.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "foo.h"

void bar(void)
{
  foo();
  puts("bar");
}
```

that are compiled and linked via

```
gcc -o program main.c -L. -lbar
gcc -shared -olibbar.so -L. -lfoo bar.o
```

Then "bar" depends on "foo" (unlike in the answer):

```
> readelf -d libbar.so
Dynamic section at offset 0xe08 contains 25 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libfoo.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x000000000000000c (INIT)               0x5b0
```

If one replaces every "foo" by "bar" in the file main.c above, one can compile and link everything to a working program

```
gcc -o program main.c -L. -lbar -Wl,-rpath-link .
```

If one keeps the "foo"-lines, linking fails because the foo-symbol cannot be resolved (the program isn't even linked against "bar").

The interesting case is the one where calls to both "foo" and "bar" occur. Now main.c is linked against "bar" which is linked against "foo", but the symbols in "foo" are still not available to main.c.

This behaviour actually makes sense because main.c might depend on a different library defining a function foo() and then it doesn't want to know about the one that "bar" uses. And if that behaviour is desired, also the optimization of not "NEEDing" libraries that aren't needed is valid.